# C# XNA 4.0 Dynamic Content

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, xna-4.0

Using XNA 4.0 I have a solution with multiple projects one of them is a card editor to create content for the solution I'm making. I've added a folder to the game content, and the card editor saves data into that folder. Is there any way to get the XML files being created inside that folder to be automatically added as content to my solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post that helped me out a lot here: http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/xna-load-all-content-files-in-a-folder/

The important part is here:

```
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string key = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

    result[key] = contentManager.Load<T>(contentManager.RootDirectory + 
                  "/" + contentFolder + "/" + key);
}
```

Basically his code checks for each file in the directory and loads them into the content pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will be helpful, but I'm wondering about getting the XML files into Visual Studio 2010 as well, because if they aren't loaded into Visual Studio can they be turned into XNB's by the compiler for Xbox game? I'm developing it for both PC and Xbox

Comment: You can load them manually as content objects or you can use the code above to put them into the pipeline. [Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/09/reading-files-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) gave a great post about it on his Blog, which often has great XNA posts. I've used the first technique, but haven't played with the other two yet. The third technique (Storage container) is often used to load XML level maps.

It's worth looking through Mr. Hargreaves blog. He posts some great examples of solutions to common XNA issues.